# JMeter variable scope in threads

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter tests which does the following:

- It makes a GET request. The request returns some ID which is extracted by a `Regular Expression Extractor` and is set to a variable `myId`.
- Another GET request is made using this ID stored in `myId`. It is important that the same ID is used as returned by the request before. Not any other ID!

This simple scenario works fine. But when I increase the "Number of Threads (users)" from 1 to (let's say) 5, I run into concurrency problems:

[image]

- Thread 1 makes the GET request and assigns the ID to `myId`.
- Thread 2 makes the GET request and assigns the ID to `myId`.
- Now thread 1 runs again and makes the second GET request but with the wrong ID as thread 2 has changed it. Now everything breaks.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Variables aren't shared between threads. The second thread shouldn't be interfering with your thread-1 ID. What's more likely is you're recapturing or failing to recapture correctly, the ID, in the second iteration of thread-1. Can you try executing with just 1 thread but several cycles?

Comment: Yes, it was helpful, but it turned out that the problem was somewhere else: I performed a login before my tests and did a log-out in a loop. I will accept your answer anyway as my problem is fixed and the Debug Sampler was a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you use the same name for the reference **myId**, if in the second extraction it doesn't find anything then myId will contain the previous extracted value.

What you can do to check this, is to put in Default Value field:

> nv_myId

as per:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

You can use a [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) to show content of variables